# Python String to List object

Tags: python

I have this String (representing a JSON value):

```
BABEL_JSON = "{
    'BD': u'Bangladesh', 
    'WF': u'Wallis y Futuna', 
    'BF': u'Burkina Faso'
}"
```

and I need to transform into a List object like this:

```
BABEL_LIST = [
    ("BD", u"Bangladesh"),
    ("WF", u"Wallis y Futuna"),
    ("BF", u"Burkina Faso")
]
```

What is the best way? to begin I tried with:

```
import json
BABEL_LIST = json.loads(str(BABEL_JSON))
```

but I have this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. If `BABEL_JSON` was a dictionary, you could just use `BABEL_JSON.items()` to get `BABEL_LIST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the best and fastest way to do it I found

```
BABEL_JSON = "{
    'BD': u'Bangladesh', 
    'WF': u'Wallis y Futuna', 
    'BF': u'Burkina Faso'
}"

BABEL_LIST = [(key, countries[key]) for key in BABEL_JSON]
```

And if you want to sort them by the name.

```
BABEL_LIST.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use literal eval as your content is not valid JSON, it is a python dictionary as a string.

literal eval safely evaluates valid python objects.

```
import ast


BABEL_JSON = """{                                                               
    'BD': u'Bangladesh',                                                        
    'WF': u'Wallis y Futuna',                                                   
    'BF': u'Burkina Faso'                                                       
}"""

myDict = ast.literal_eval(BABEL_JSON)
print(myDict.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a valid json string. In json, strings are written with `"`. The `u` in front of a string is not allowed too. You have to transform your initial json-like string to a valid one:

```
import json
BABEL_JSON ="""{
    'BD': u'Bangladesh', 
    'WF': u'Wallis y Futuna', 
    'BF': u'Burkina Faso'
}"""
s = BABEL_JSON.replace(": u", ": ").replace("'", '"')
print json.loads(s).items()
```

See http://ideone.com/OxPml

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
a = json.loads(l)
zip(a.keys(),a.values())
```

another way

```
import ast
a = ast.literal_eval(l)
zip(a.keys(),a.values())
```

Comment: more efficient to use `a.items()`

Answer (score 0):

Or use regex like this:

```
import re

BABEL_JSON = """{
    'BD': u'Bangladesh', 
    'WF': u'Wallis y Futuna', 
    'BF': u'Burkina Faso'
}"""

print re.findall(r"'([^']+)': u'([^']+)'", BABEL_JSON)
```

Output:

```
[('BD', 'Bangladesh'), ('WF', 'Wallis y Futuna'), ('BF', 'Burkina Faso')]
```